# Return on my function doesn't work if using sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am populating a text box with the returned value of a function, but it doesn't work if I run the sql code inside the function. I can remove the sql related code and it works. so i'm stumped.

And by "doesn't work" i mean that the text box never gets populated with anything. it remains blank.

thanks

```
public string CreateResident()
{
    string result = "hmm";
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=DELLXPS\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Warren_SEINDATASYSTEMS; Integrated Security=true;");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[NewUsers]([ResidentAccountNumber],[ResidentName],[ResidentAddress],[NumberOfVisitors],[TempPass],[Role])VALUES(@ResidentAccountNumber,@ResidentName,@ResidentAddress,@NumberOfVisitors,(select cast((Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%10) as varchar(1)) + char(ascii('a')+(Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%25)) + char(ascii('A')+(Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%25)) + left(newid(),5)),'resident')";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection;

    SqlParameter ResidentAccountNumber = new SqlParameter();
    ResidentAccountNumber.ParameterName = "@ResidentAccountNumber";
    ResidentAccountNumber.Value = txtboxResidenetAccountNumber.Text.Trim();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(ResidentAccountNumber);
    SqlParameter ResidentName = new SqlParameter();
    ResidentName.ParameterName = "@ResidentName";
    ResidentName.Value = txtboxResidentName.Text.Trim();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(ResidentName);
    SqlParameter ResidentAddress = new SqlParameter();
    ResidentAddress.ParameterName = "@ResidentAddress";
    ResidentAddress.Value = txtboxResidentAddress.Text.Trim();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(ResidentAddress);
    SqlParameter NumberOfVisitors = new SqlParameter();
    NumberOfVisitors.ParameterName = "@NumberofVisitors";
    NumberOfVisitors.Value = txtboxNumberOfVisitors.Text.Trim();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(NumberOfVisitors);


    try
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        result = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = ex.Message;
    }

    return result;
}

protected void btnCreateResident_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtboxTempPassword.Text = CreateResident();
}
```

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: What you mean inside a function? where you get the error, and what error is?

Comment: you need to  SqlDataReader to read the result

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Please supply an exception message, error, behavior, anything that can more accurately describe what you mean by this. Second, you are running an insert statement so you should use `ExecuteNonQuery` and not `ExecuteScalar`. Finally, if the query is in question then trouble shoot it in SSMS and manually add the parameters above the statement to see what happens. Finally your parameter values should reflect the type as it is persisted in your database. IE. number of visitors, if that is an int in the database then convert the text to an int using `int.Parse`.

Comment: I've never seen values used this way -- with an embedded select statement. I believe this is just wrong.

Comment: ill try the data reader. but im confused, even if it didn't read the sql result, why isn't it returning "hmm"?

Comment: It is not returning because it is throwing an exception -- **YOUR SQL IS NOT LEGAL**

Comment: why isn't it showing me the error? I edited the question to show the try catch, but that doesn't show any errors either. the page just refreshes.

the data does get put in correctly however.

Comment: put a breakpoint and see what happens

Comment: Why not generate that initial password in your C# code and pass in a param? That would make your sql simpler.

Comment: chuckles* because this is how google told me to do it. 

I switched to using a datareader and returned the value i want. that works.

thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is wrong and you have a lot of problems but I want to show you a way to make your code more readable.  Format it like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[NewUsers] ([ResidentAccountNumber],[ResidentName],[ResidentAddress], NumberOfVisitors],[TempPass], Role])
                    VALUES(
                      @ResidentAccountNumber,
                      @ResidentName,
                      @ResidentAddress,
                      @NumberOfVisitors,
                      (select cast((Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%10) as varchar(1)) + char(ascii('a')+(Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%25)) + char(ascii('A')+(Abs(Checksum(NewId()))%25)) + left(newid(),5)),
                      'resident')";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection;
```

We know that a select in a VALUES constructor is not legal so that is one problem.

Also having a SELECT without a from seems strange -- did you copy your code correctly?

You are using ExecuteScalar -- do you know what that does?  It shouldn't include a query that includes INSERT query.

I'm guessing you probably want a stored procedure.

Comment: thank you. unfortunately, i do not know what it means. iv been using the datareader (switched to that to solve this problem.  the scaler is just the example i was following.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest do not write query in C# code, you must use Stored Procedure for the same purpose.
If you want your query to return some id, primary key or some value then you must write query for that after your insert query.
you can use the following keywords in your select query,if you want to return id from table.

`SCOPE_IDENTITY` returns the last IDENTITY value inserted into an IDENTITY column in the same scope.

`IDENT_CURRENT` returns the last identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope.

`@@IDENTITY` returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session, across all scopes.

If you want to return only one record then use `ExecuteScalar` else you can use `ExecuteReader`.

If your only purpose is to insert data into the table then you should use `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: switching to executereader and using OUTPUT in the query gave the result i was looking for.

Comment: @viveknuna -- updating question with answer is not really how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of comments I went with `ExecuteReader` instead of the `ExecuteScaler`. And changed the statement to return a value

```
INSERT INTO [table] ([fields]) OUTPUT Inserted.MyColumn VALUES(values)
```

C# Code:

```
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            result = reader[0].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = ex.Message;
    }

    return result;
```